# How to show JSON volley request reponse's object (in HTML) form in textView?

Tags: java, android, html

I have a JSON response in which object values are in HTML form. In which i have a Paragraph, a img src and video src link. How can i parse or show the image and video onto the Activity. Any help would be appreciated.

Response I'm receiving from server(only showing one object here)

```
{
"description":"<p>The Sarawak Ministry of Modernisation of Agriculture</p>\n
<p><video src=\"https://myurl.biz/media/media/Nokia_X3_sample_video.3gp.3gp\" autoplay=\"autoplay\" controls=\"controls\" width=\"300\" height=\"150\">
<span id=\"mce_marker\" data-mce-type=\"bookmark\">ï»¿â</span></video>
</p>\n<p><img src=\"https://myurl.biz/media/media/bird_SJhLHPo.jpg\" width=\"547\" height=\"264\" /></p>" 
}
```

I have tried :

```
txtDetails.setText( Html.fromHtml(extras.getString("details"));
```

Actual Result I'm receiving in my text view:

```
The Sarawak Ministry of Modernisation of Agriculture,

ï»¿â€‹
```

Comment: Maybe look into using a WebView?

Comment: I can't use that i do not have a .HTML file.

Comment: What you have is pretty much the body of one, you can add the necessary tags and use that or look into building a nice looking design, extracting the data (fields between the <p> tags) and putting it in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is impossible. You can't display an image/video in a TextView (this is not a browser). First, you need to parse the HTML. Then, once you have the components you can plug them in separate views. For example,

1. You **parse the HTML** (there are a lot of frameworks for that)
2. **Get the image URL** link and **use [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/)** (popular framework for displaying images from URLs) to display it on your Activity.
3. Get the paragraph and display it in a TextView
   etc..

Comment: Thanks, for clearing confusion, i want to know how to parse that object to extract the img and video URL.

Comment: So, can i'm able to get the image now i used Html.ImageGetter() can i do the same for the video, i have two URL one for image and other for video.